# How to get start and end date when Outlook makes an iCal request to my web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, outlook, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I can see lots of examples of how using web API / web service one can return a list of appointments in iCal format using DDay library. However all the examples suggest creating a generic method, i.e. `getAppointments()`, which takes no parameters. Then to paste the API/method link in Outlook Calendar or Google Calendar to get the sync to work. This works fine.

The problem is that `getAppointments()` will return all appointments of past and future, how do I know which dates Outlook or Google want the appointments for? Will Outlook or Google Calendar automatically include in the URL the dates they need the appointment for?

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet of how you are achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible unless you use something like a CALDAV. The simpler option is set your date range, we picked up 1 month earlier from today to 6 months from in future ie total of 7m to return the data.